# Simple ruby loop to get sum of cubes

Tags: ruby

I was given this problem to solve with Ruby:

Compute the sum of cubes for a given range a through b. Write a method called sum_of_cubes to accomplish this task.

I wrote this:

```
def sum_of_cubes(a, b)
    sum = 0
    for x in a..b
        c = x ** 3
    end
    sum += c
end
```

I got the value of the cube of b. What is wrong with this code? How can I solve this problem with a simple loop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I would use [Enumerable#reduce](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce)

```
def sum_of_cubes min, max
  (min..max).reduce(0) { |a, b| a + b ** 3 }
end
```

A little explanation of what's happening here

---

We start with range `(min..max)` which is an [Enumerable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html)

```
irb> (1..3).is_a? Enumerable
=> true
```

Using the `reduce` instance method we get from `Enumerable`, we can use a block of code that gets called for each item in our (enumerable) range, and ultimately returns a single value.

The function name makes sense if you think "take my group of items and *reduce* them to a single value."

Here's our block

```
{ |a, b| a + b ** 3 }
```

- We called `reduce` with `0` which is the **initial value** given to the block's `a` param
- The return value of the block is passed to the block's `a` param on subsequent calls
- Each item in the range will be passed to the block's `b` param

---

Let's step through and see how it works

1. `(1..3).reduce(0) { |a, b| a + b ** 3 }`
2. the first block call gets `a=0` (initial value) and `b=1` (first item in our range)

   the return value of our block is `0 + 1 ** 3` or `1`
3. the second block call gets `a=1` (return value from the last call) and `b=2` (the second item in our range)

   the return value of our block is `1 + 2 ** 3` or `9`
4. the third block call gets `a=9` (return value from the last call) and `b=3` (the third and last item in our range)

   the return value of our block is `9 + 3 ** 3` or `36`
5. the final return value of `reduce` is the last-called block's return value

   in this case `36`

Comment: While this is most Rubyish form, it might not be appropriate for someone just starting to find their feet in algorithms.

Comment: Someone trying to find their feet in algorithms should absolutely learn about functions like map, reduce, and friends. Also, for each version, see what happens if the greater value is passed in before the lesser value. If using ruby 2.0+, might be good to use named arguments (that are named 'min' and 'max', not just 'a' and 'b'.

Comment: @Amadan, I have to disagree with you. There's no substitute for teaching the idiomatic way of doing things in the language you're learning. Sorry, I didn't provide the explanation the same time I provided the answer.

Comment: Hmm. Depends if he's learning basic programming or Ruby - and based on the mistake in the OP, I'd say it was the former. `reduce` behind the scenes does the exact same thing, after all. If I were to teach a functional language, I would still first make an unabstracted version, then define the reduce operation, and only then use the ready-made one from the library and introduce it as an idiom. But I do agree at least there is a benefit to also showing and explaining the idiom itself.

Comment: @Amadan, fair enough. I should've identified that the mistake was elementary enough that perhaps teaching some fundamentals first would've been more beneficial. Between the two of us, I think we helped him out pretty well, then :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to have `sum += c` *inside* the loop. And then return `sum` when done.

Comment: I tried putting that after c = x ** 3 but the console printed a..b

Comment: Yeah... Ruby will return the last evaluated expression from a function, and the last expression is `a..b`. Which is why I said "then return `sum` when done`. Just stick `sum` or `return sum` as a last line.

Answer (score 3):

Here’s another way to calculate this. It doesn’t address your problems with your loop but I think it’s worth mentioning.

The sum of cubes of integers `13 + 23 + 33 + ... + n3` is given by the formula `(n(n + 1)/2)2`, so the sum of cubes of a given *range* `min..max` is therefore given by:

```
(max(max + 1)/2)2 - ((min-1)((min-1) + 1)/2)2
```

In code this could look like:

```
def sum_of_cubes_fixed min, max
  lower = min - 1
  (((max * (max + 1))/2) ** 2) - (((lower * (lower + 1))/2) ** 2)
end
```

This code avoids the loop, and so is O(1) rather than O(n) (almost – I’m hand waving a bit here, the time complexity of the multiplications and exponentiations will depend on the size of the numbers). For small sized ranges you won’t notice this, but for larger sizes the difference between this and the loop version becomes increasingly obvious. I haven’t done any strict benchmarks, but a quick test on my machine with the range 1 to 10,000,000 takes several seconds with the `reduce` method but is almost instantaneous with this method.

Normally I would just use `reduce` for something like this, but the structure of the task suggested that there might be a better way. With the help of Google I found the formula and came up with a more efficient solution (at least for large ranges).

Answer (score 3):

`(a..b).map{|i| i**3 }.inject(&:+)` map and inject does the job, elegantly.

EDIT: Although it walks through the list twice ;)